# How do you localize the Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, localization

When downloading Twitters Bootstrap v3.1.1 I try to use some of the reusable items. These items have english text which I can find and easily override, but there are some messages that pops up and does field validation that I cannot find -- probably because I am not familiar with the framework.

How could I proceed to find out more about these fields?

For instance, the validation messages in the `form-signin` username has a validation message. How do I override this one? Where is the text located? Is there a pattern/best practice for doing this kind of localization?

So if you put this example into http://bootply.com it becomes easy to see what happens.

Field text and placeholder text is easy to localize.

But when you try to put in invalid email address you get a pop up. *How do I localize this pop up* when you put in NO-EMAIL and press submit?

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
      Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe some code ?
Try to copy-paste your form here http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: thanks for the reference @woj_jas, checking it out. I am not familiar with the Twitter Bootstrap and have no clue on how to override localization. I tried to search for the text I want to override but can't find it: of course code is necessary-- I did search a lot without finding everything, probably because I'm not familiar with the framework.

Comment: But what do you need ? Please copy scrap of your code to bootply.com and post it below , I will see and do everything to help you. I'm assuming that you are trying to write contact form or something

Comment: @woj_jas ok example is ready to put into bootply.com, excellent tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is in the HTML 5 control. You can override this on the `oninvalid` event on the input element.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-post addresse" required autofocus oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('your message')" >
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm Almost 100% sure that popup is taken from jquery.js and you will have to dig there.
This text (about email) changes language . I'm writing from Poland and I have polish pop-ups.
If you want to use other validation jquery plugin

check this [Unheap JS Repository](http://www.unheap.com/?s=validation)

When you use Ketchup Validator you will have custom validating messages

Comment: So you propose just work around it. I'll try to dig alittle inside the jquery plugin, it links to the cdn google version.

Comment: In bootstrap you have jquery.js file and bootstrap.js file , so it has to take elements from there.